# Target column greyed out :File Explorer Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-11, windows-11-preview

File Explorer: Target greyed out!
Can't set custom target location of File Explorer Windows 11[image: File Explorer Properties]

Answer (score 1):

What you see is entirely normal.

File Explorer is built right into Windows 11 (and earlier Windows) and you cannot change where it runs from in Windows 11.

File Explorer is undergoing big changes in Windows 11 Insider and so it is best just to leave File Explorer properties that cannot be changed alone.

Comment: I changed it once like last year in windows 10, opens File explorer directly in my Drive not Quick access or "This PC". If its greyed-out. There should be a way to access its feature.

Comment: Windows 11 is very different - it is not like Windows 10.

Comment: So, they should remove this option, Its temptation lol, neither I can disable lock-Screen when waking-up from Hibernation in Windows 11.

Comment: You would need to feed back that request to Microsoft.

Comment: That's identical to the `File Explorer` shortcut found on Windows 10 in the Start Menu's "WIndows System" folder. Don't have Windows 11, but can't you still select your drive in Explorer > `right-click` > `Send to >` > `Desktop (Create shortcut)`?

Comment: That is not the same as  target properties.   And 11 is quite different from 10

Comment: Not so different that the Properties dialogs aren't identical!

Answer (score 1):

I have to post as an answer to incluce a screenshot. Here's the `Properties` dialog for thw Windows 10 shortcut:

[image]

that is found in:

- `shell:Programs\System Tools`

### How is that different than your screenshot???

Whereas as shortcut created as I described has an editble `Target` field:

[image]

Double-clicking that shortcut opens `Explorer` directly to the `C:` drive.

Your indistinct pronoun reference: "*That* is not the same..." leaves much to the imagination, as my examples demonstrate that, even under Windows 10, some shortcuts have an editable `Target` field and some don't.

If you're claiming you changed something so that <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> opened **Explorer** to your drive, you should edit your question to clarify this. Perhaps you played with values found under:

- `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\FileExplorer\Config`

[image: Registry ScreenShot]

Comment: I once changed its target in Windows 10, by creating a new shortcut and pinning it to the taskbar as I remember, its not working now.